# WebClient prematurely closed DURING response

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring webclient to connect to the netty webflux server.

I'm receiving this error after 20-30 minutes when consumer is idle.

- Webflux server is running in AWS EC2
- Fronted by Spring cloud gateway deployed in AWS EKS-EC2
- AWS ELB as ingress load-balancer to Spring cloud gateway
- Previously I used to get timeout on webflux Server due to AWS ELB Idle timeout configuration. So now webflux service is sending heartbeat message to client every 20 seconds

Is that because connection is closed from server-side or the problem is in client-side?

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException:
    Connection prematurely closed DURING response

Suppressed:
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
            |_ checkpoint ? Body from GET https://*** [DefaultClientResponse]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after 20-30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

This is generally caused by the server side closing the idle connection.

On the client side, you can configure how long an idle connection is used for by invoking the `maxIdleTime` method on the `ConnectionProvider` builder. Example taken from [Connection Pool Reference Docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_connection_pool_2).

```
ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                .maxConnections(50)
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .build()
```

> maxIdleTime - The maximum time (resolution: ms) that this connection stays idle in the connection pool. By default, maxIdleTime is not specified.

> maxLifeTime - The maximum time (resolution: ms) that this connection stays alive. By default, maxLifeTime is not specified.

This note from the [reference docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-pool-timeout) is particularly key for the issue you are seeing with the target server closing the connection before the client.

> When you configure maxIdleTime, you should consider the idle timeout configuration on the target server. Choose a configuration that is equal to or less than the one on the target server. By doing so, you can reduce the I/O issues caused by a connection closed by the target server.

[maxIdleTime JavaDocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.ConnectionPoolSpec.html#maxIdleTime-java.time.Duration-)

[maxLifeTime Javadocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.ConnectionPoolSpec.html#maxLifeTime-java.time.Duration-)

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not sure how is this related to IdleTime out. I'm seeing this disconnection after 20-30 minutes. And server is sending heartbeat message response, which client is receiving it until this disconnection issue happening.

Comment: do you know what either the idle connection timeout or lifetime connection timeout settings are set to on the remote server?

Comment: There are multiple layers involved here
Webclient -> AWS R53-> ELB LoadBalancer -> SpringCloudGateway -> Webflux service.
My suspicion is AWS ELB load balancer may be playing a part here...In my local environment, if I directly go through the spring cloud gateway, never came across timeout. But not sure what is that configuration..
I already fixed webflux service, by sending heartbeat message every 20 seconds to client...Few times, there's period, when there wont be any data for webflux service to stream, but still want connection to be maintained.